# Need help passing values "AngularJS"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

i need some help trying to pass:

(Page 1 -> Module 1 -> Controller 1) to (Page 2 -> Module 2 -> Controller 2)

like that:

Module informes - Controller InformesCtrl

```
//Page 1
<html lang="en" class="no-js"  ng-app="informes">
<a ng-href="../node-informes/node-informes.html">
    <p class="text-center text-truncate">
        <small ng-click="nodeID(item.nid)">{{item.title}}</small>
    </p>
</a>
```

Module node-informes - Controller NodeInformesCtrl

```
//Page 2
<html lang="en" class="no-js"  ng-app="node-informes">
<div ng-controller="NodeInformesCtrl" ng-value=""></div>
```

I tried with $rootScope, creating service, $broadcast, $on, and a lot of other things. I really need your help because i don't know how to solve that. If you can give me some tips.

**What I really need is to store the "selected value" of a list and print in a different page.**

How would you solve that??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those angular apps have nothing to do with each other as they are run in completely different pages. You could use query string in url and parse that on second page

Comment: Or combine the pages/apps into one using an angular router and store data in a service to be shared across components

Comment: Supposed that. Maybe the first answeris the more acceptable, because i will have to use different pages in one app. So i will try and post my feedback.

Answer (score -1):

There should be a parent module in which you are injecting the child modules. Create a service in the parent module with getters and setters. you can inject this service to both the controllers in child modules.

Comment: There is no parent/child relationship between two completely different pages and apps

Comment: Yes like @charlietfl said, it's not possible

Comment: In that case why don't you store the value somewhere and retrieve it in the other page? if it is a temporary save you can use local storage.

Comment: No, for example you can put {{item.id}} in the href using templates. That means that it will use the template you choose independient from the item selected. I'm trying that now. Give me some mins.